# Matrix multiplication in $SO(3)$ that fixes row

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups

I want to find all matrices $G \in SO(3)$ that do not change the first row of elements in $SO(3)$ when right multiplying by $G$, i.e.

$$
\{ G \in SO(3): \forall A \in SO(3) \quad A =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}\;, \\
 \;\text{if} \; A' = A G \;\text{then}\; a_{11}' = a_{11}, a_{12}' = a_{12}, a_{13}' = a_{13} \}
$$

I found that the matrices $G$ for having this with left-multiplication are precisely the rotations

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\
0 & \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
$$
around the first coordinate axis, but I can't seem to find a good characterization for the matrices on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider $A\in\left\{I,\ \pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0},\ \pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0}\right\}$.

Comment: Corresponding matrices $G$ share one row with the identity matrix. For each one of these $A$'s, the other two rows of $G$ don't matter, but how do I make them part of $SO(3)$?

Comment: Also, what's the geometrical intuition behind sharing a row with the identity matrix? I can see it fixes a coordinate when right multiplying by a column vector, but what about left multiplying by a row vector?

Comment: @Mark Let $v=(1,0,0)^T$. You want to find all $G$s such that $v^TA=v^TAG$ for every $A\in SO(3)$, don't you?

Comment: Now take transposes. Then $A^Tv = G^TA^Tv$. In other words, $G^T$ fixes the first column of $A^T$, i.e. the first column of $A^T$ is the axis of rotation of $G^T$. Since $A^T$ is arbitrary, this means *every* unit vector is an axis of rotation of $G^T$, but this is possible if and only if ...

Comment: $G$ is the 2-sphere? But that's not a rotation, and I'm expecting something 1-dimensional. Um...

Comment: @Mark Huh? What do you mean? There is only one rotation matrix that has more than one rotation axes.

Comment: Well the identity matrix works. But aren't there more? I'm expecting something isomorphic to $SO(2)$.

Comment: I was confusing the set of matrices $G$ with a single matrix before. But still, is there only one matrix $G$ in my set?

Comment: @Mark If you want to find all $G\in SO(3)$s such that $(1,0,0)A=(1,0,0)AG$ for all $A\in SO(3)$, then yes, the only feasible matrix is the identity matrix.